# Automatically turn on if battery is full.

Tags: power, battery

I want to power a RPi off of a battery and need it to autonomously turn on once its battery is charged. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

A simple voltage controlled switch to apply the primary power to the RPi would be the simplest.
You would have to make sure that once "ON" it would lock "ON" until reset, the reason for this is not wanting the RPi properly shutdown when power was approaching to low of voltage.
A good battery charging circuit would incorporate the power switch into its circuit.

Simplest form would be a Zener controlled MOSFET switch kind of like this:

[image: Zener controlled MOSFET switch circuit]